# SFTP connection failure with error code -43

Tags: sftp

I am tying to connect to sftp server via testapp using curl_7.74 and libssh2_1.8.2. this working in ubuntu 16.04 desktop but not on my embedded environment.

following error is thrown
root@phyboard-segin-imx6ul-2:~# ./sftptest
st.st_size:[0]

- Trying 115.249.3.130:2222...
- Connected to sftp-xxxxxxxx.mydomain.net (xxx.249.3.130) port 2222 (#0)
- Failure establishing ssh session: -43, Failed getting banner
- Closing connection 0
  curl told us 2

somebody pls throw some light on it :)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue with curl (7.64) connecting to a web host. It doesn't happen every time, but often enough to be a concern.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I don't know exactly what's happening, but according to the [source code](https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/blob/b27383918eefe9f49b982a7e553f1dce65639afd/include/libssh2.h#L581), -43 is LIBSSH2_ERROR_SOCKET_RECV, which the [banner_receive](https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/blob/b27383918eefe9f49b982a7e553f1dce65639afd/src/session.c#L152) function documents as "some kinda error" receiving the banner. I'm guessing the server isn't sending (all of) the response. Key exchange, maybe?